# Win32 Window Text issue

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I have issues understanding the `GetWindowTextA()` function from the Win32 API.

According to the Microsoft documentation, **`nMaxCount`** is the maximum characters to copy to buffer **`lpString`** including the null character.

So, does `GetWindowTextA()` automatically write the null termination character into to buffer **`lpString`** or do I have to manually add the null termination character into **`lpString`**?

This is the `GetWindowTextA()` definition from Microsoft Documentation:

```
int GetWindowTextA(
  [in]  HWND  hWnd,
  [out] LPSTR lpString,
  [in]  int   nMaxCount
);
```

Here is the code:

```
char M_Buff[20];

SetWindowTextA(M_SEND_EDIT_TEXT,"Hello World");

GetWindowTextA(M_SEND_EDIT_TEXT,M_Buff,20);  //Do i have to add  the null termination caracter into M_Buff myself  or it is put automatically ?

printf("String is %s\n",M_Buff);
```

Comment: Experimentation shows that GetWindowText always adds a NULL for you. GetWindowText returns the length of the string returned which may be in the range of zero to maxSize-1.

Comment: @SteveValliere: The identifier `NULL` (or `nullptr`) should only used for pointers, not for characters. To specify a null character, it is common to write `'\0'`.

Comment: `So, does GetWindowTextA() automatically write the null termination character into to buffer` - Definitely yes. The vast majority of win32 apis were hardened years back to ensure null termination when dealing with string copies.

Answer (score 3):

If the `GetWindowTextA()` function reports success by returning a non-zero value, then it will also write a terminating null character to the memory buffer. There is no need to add one yourself.

The [official documentation of that function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) does not clearly specify that it will always write a null character to the string. It only specifies this clearly for the edge case of the string being truncated:

> If the string is as long or longer than the buffer, the string is truncated and terminated with a null character.

However, this statement does not make sense if it does not also do this for the general case of the string not being truncated. Therefore, it is safe to assume that it will also write a terminating null character when the string is not being truncated.

Also, the documentation states the following:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in characters, of the copied string, not including the terminating null character.

This statement also implies that it will write a terminating null character to the buffer.

Also, as one of the other answers has pointed out, the parameter type `LPSTR` implies that the buffer will be null-terminated after the function returns.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation does not say that the result is null terminated if the string is shorter than the buffer. I know that it is, and it would be strange if it were not. But I can understand the OPs confusion because this is not stated explicitly.

Comment: @john: Yes, the documentation does not clearly specify that it will always write a null character to the string. It only specifies this clearly for the edge case of the string being truncated. However, this statement does not make sense if it does not also do this for the general case of the string not being truncated. Therefore, it is safe to assume that it will also write a terminating null character when the string is not being truncated.

Comment: @john: The documentation also states the following: "If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in characters, of the copied string, not including the terminating null character." This also implies that a null character is being written. I have edited my answer to include this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Although [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) for the `GetWindowTextA` function is not *completely* unambiguous about what happens if the returned string does *not* get truncated (if it does, then it is clearly stated that a terminating null character is included), we can deduce that it is (or *should* be) always null-terminated from the definition of the argument type for `lpString`, which is `LPSTR`.

From [the documentation for that type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):

> `LPSTR`      A pointer to a null-terminated string
> of 8-bit Windows (ANSI) characters.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much guesswork involved as long as you look at the right documentation (the SDK header files, *winnt.h* in particular). The interesting part here is, that `LPSTR` isn't just a pointer, it also comes with an [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects):

> ```c
> typedef _Null_terminated_ CHAR *NPSTR, *LPSTR, *PSTR;
> ```

Since [`GetWindowTextA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) is using `LPSTR` as it's `_Out_` paramter type, it inherits the SAL annotations along with it.

If there were a path through the implementation of `GetWindowTextA` that didn't zero-terminate the output buffer, then that would produce a build error, and there would be no *User32.dll*. If there is a *User32.dll* module in your system, you can safely assume that its implementation meets the SAL annotations. Specifically, the buffer passed into `GetWindowTextA` will **always** be zero-terminated on return (irrespective of whether the function call succeeded or failed).

Comment: What if the buffer passed is read-only and not null-terminated on input? Or if it's an invalid address?

Comment: @adr A function makes no promises *at all* if the preconditions are violated. The formal parameter `lpString` has the following annotation: `_Out_writes_(nMaxSize)`. It is an output parameter (`_Out_`), so its contents on input are considered indeterminate. However, the entire buffer must be writable (`_writes_(nMaxSize)`). The buffer can thus be not null-terminated on input, but it needs to be writable, and (obviously) must be valid.